# Show delete link on comments

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page which shows the comments posted by all users. Here I need to show a delete link on the side of the comments posted by that current logged in user and he should be able to delete that comment too (like in Facebook, Orkut or any Blogging site). The sample code which I have tried is:

```
<?php
$user_id = 1;
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("blog", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM replies");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $replies = $row;
  if($replies['poster_id' == $user_id]){
      $delete = '<a href="#">Delete</a>';
  }

  echo $replies['poster_id']?></a>&nbsp;¦&nbsp;<?php echo $replies['reply_text']?>&nbsp;¦&nbsp;  <?php echo $delete?></div>

  <?php echo "<br />";
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Here I have given the user_id which is hardcoded here. What I got is, delete link is displayed on all comments. I need to display delete link for user_id with "1" only. Can anyone suggest me to get the solution...Thanks in Advance...

Comment: if($replies['poster_id' == $user_id]){
need to be

if($replies['poster_id'] == $user_id){

Answer (score 0):

```
if($replies['poster_id' == $user_id]){
```

need to be

```
  $delete ='';
  if($replies['poster_id'] == $user_id){
      $delete = '<a href="#">Delete</a>';
  }
```

you need to unset the `$delete` variable in every loop, if not once its get a value and present it in every cycle of loop

Comment: @Haim Evgi: I am getting the delete link for each comment. It should be shown for comments which have user_id 1

Comment: i understand this, did u try to change this line ?

Comment: yes i changed..Now the code looks like: $replies = $row;
  $delete ='';
   if($replies['poster_id' == $user_id]){
    $delete = '<a href="#">Delete</a>';
    
   }

Comment: the if condition need to be :   if($replies['poster_id'] == $user_id){  did its work ?

Comment: here its showing all the comments with delete link near by it.

Comment: Then you still need to unset / reset $delete in the loop. That should be the first or second statement in the loop (at least before the if-statement).